# Трудности переводов

Tags: переводы

Часто сталкиваюсь с такой трудностью при переводе с японского. Дело в том, что у них много форм местоимения "я". Оно зависит у них от пола говорящего, от формы, в которой он говорит о себе и т.д. Например, самые распространенные мужские "я": "ватакуши" ("ватакуси") - очень вежливое, "ваташи" ("ватаси") - нейтрально-вежливое, "боку" - нейтральное, но чаще так говорят молодые, и "орэ" - грубоватое. Но я совершенно не представляю себе, как это отражать в русском переводе. А ведь эти местоимения придают эмоциональную окраску как тексту, так и персонажу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Русский язык не настолько разнообразен на личные местоимения, поэтому придется вам использовать другие языковые средства, чтобы подчеркнуть личность героя и эмоциональную окраску речи. Тысячи их!